# How do you pass statements through an addEventListener?

Tags: actionscript

Iv been trying to pass arguments through an addEventListener event in actionscript such as...

```
target.addEventListener("pComp", rakeSoil(target));
```

but i get errors.

Iv tried to google but no luck :/

Thanks for replying if you do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an additional method as your event listener:

```
target.addEventListener ("pComp", targetListener);

...

private function targetListener (event:Event):void {

   rakeSoil (event.currentTarget);

}
```

Comment: Or, if you have the ability, you can just make rakeSoil take in the event, and then access currentTarget, instead of taking in the currentTarget.

Answer (score 4):

The target is already passed as part of the event, either `event.currentTarget` or `event.target` will be what you want.

If you want something else passed, create a custom event. Add the property to the custom event.

Answer (score 0):

How this is what you want:

```
   {
        var target:EventDispatcher = ...;
        Function rakeSoil = function (e:Event):void 
        {
            // handle target 
        }

        target.addEventListener("pComp", rakeSoil);
    }
```

rakeSoil is a first class function(or closure), when event is dispatched, it will be invoked, and you can access 'target' in it.

EDIT:

Have a look at [Closure (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

I have always found anonymous functions to be more trouble than they are worth. I would simply follow the standard event handler code layout. It's more formal and takes a little more effort up front, but there is no ambiguity and it is far more readable when you return to it a year from now (reduces head-scratching duration):

```
//  Target extends EventDispatcher
private var target:Target;

public function listenToTarget();
{
    target = new Target();
    target.addEventListener("pComp", pCompHandler);
}

private function pCompHandler(event:Event):void
{
    target.rakeSoil();
}
```

Although, now that I look at it more closely, why are you having this object do something that Target should be capable of handling internally on its own?